EF Core Add Migration Error: Duplicate Seed Entity for 'AdditionalProductSubType'
I am encountering an issue when running the Add-Migration command in my EF Core project. The command fails with the following error:

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The seed entity for entity type 'AdditionalProductSubType' cannot be added because another seed entity with the key value 'Id:1' has already been added.)
System.InvalidOperationException: The seed entity for entity type 'AdditionalProductSubType' cannot be added because another seed entity with the key value 'Id:1' has already been added.

This error occurs while trying to generate a migration for the AdditionalProductSubType table. I have verified that my seed data contains no duplicate Id values.
Here are the relevant sections of my code and setup.
Seed data configuration: the seed data is defined in the AdditionalProductSubTypeSeed class as follows:
public class AdditionalProductSubTypeSeed : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AdditionalProductSubType>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AdditionalProductSubType> builder)
    {
        builder.HasData(
            new AdditionalProductSubType { Id = 1, ParentTypeId = 4, TypeName = "Young Driver" },
            new AdditionalProductSubType { Id = 2, ParentTypeId = 4, TypeName = "Premium Location Fee" },
            new AdditionalProductSubType { Id = 3, ParentTypeId = 4, TypeName = "Out of Hours Fee" }
        );
    }
}

Migration code: the migration file contains the following relevant code for the AdditionalProductSubType table:
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "ADDITIONALPRODUCTSUBTYPES",
    schema: "dbo",
    columns: table => new
    {
        ID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        PARENTTYPEID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        TYPENAME = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_ADDITIONALPRODUCTSUBTYPES", x => x.ID);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_ADDITIONALPRODUCTSUBTYPES_ADDITIONALPRODUCTTYPE_PARENTTYPEID",
            column: x => x.PARENTTYPEID,
            principalSchema: "dbo",
            principalTable: "ADDITIONALPRODUCTTYPE",
            principalColumn: "Id");
    });

migrationBuilder.InsertData(
    schema: "dbo",
    table: "ADDITIONALPRODUCTSUBTYPES",
    columns: new[] { "ID", "PARENTTYPEID", "TYPENAME" },
    values: new object[,]
    {
        { 1, 4, "Young Driver" },
        { 2, 4, "Premium Location Fee" },
        { 3, 4, "Out of Hours Fee" }
    });

My environment:

EF Core Version: 7.0
Database: SQL Server
Development Environment: Windows 10, .NET 7

Why is EF Core detecting duplicate seed data when there are no apparent duplicates in the code?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
What I have tried:

Verified that there are no duplicate Id values in the seed data
Checked all previous migrations for duplicate seed data for the AdditionalProductSubType table
Examined the AppDbContextModelSnapshot file to ensure no duplicate seed data exists


AppDbContextModelSnapshot is a snapshot of what EF thinks your data looks like, but is not necessarily representative of the actual data in the database. Have you checked the database directly for records with ID 1? This could be the cause for the seed exception.

I get this error during the migration add phase. Does it matter if there is anything in the database?

Yes - if you're attempting to migrate a database that already has data, and your migration violates a key constraint, your migration will fail.
